# MS Access If Function

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm not using SQL at this point, I'm just trying to define a function using query design function in MS Access 2010.

What i'm trying to do:
So turns out that I have a 5 month spread (Jan,Feb..May) where each month is a column. Turns out that at times May has a value and January does not, but it should. All the values are either one or null.

What I'm trying to do is write an if function of this sort:

Jan15new: Iff([May-15]=1,[Jan-15]=1,[Jan-15])

However, when I run the query with this iff function I got a column full of negative ones that doesn't abide by the rules of this if function.

If you can shed somelight that would be great!
thanks,

Comment: Can you supply some of your sample data for May and Jan? Is that the statement you have??  IFF is not an access statement, IIF is. Also there appears to be a stray = in the true part of your statement. Can you post the statement exactly as it appears?

Comment: Thanks gene, Rachel nailed it.

Comment: The numerical value of `True` in Access and Visual Basic is `-1` (in other words, all bits are set).  This is in contrast to most other languages (C-derived languages, for example) and database systems (SQL Server, for example), where it is `1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This formula returns a 1 if May-15 = 1, otherwise returns whatever value is in Jan-15:

```
Jan15new: IIf([May-15]=1,1,[Jan-15])
```

Answer (score 0):

If the values in your formula are Boolean values, you do not need to compare them to anything, and you should not be comparing them to numbers:

```
Jan15new: IIf([May-15]=True,[Jan-15]=True,[Jan-15])
```

That's actually meaningless, because it is equivalent to this:

```
Jan15new: IIf([May-15],[Jan-15],[Jan-15])
```